# Creating new table where timestamps have the same day

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database including `time` column that saves time as timestamps in a string format like `'2020-10-19T04:49:15.651867Z'` with `Z` at the end.
I want to select timestamps with the same day and put them into a new table. I have tried the following:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS (SELECT * FROM old_table WHERE DAY(time) = 20)
```

and I get ERROR 1292 (22007): Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2020-10-19T04:49:15.651867Z'.

I thought the problem is with `DAY(time) = 20` but the following code works well and shows all entries with the same day:

```
 SELECT * FROM old_table WHERE DAY(time) = '20';
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: `'2020-10-19T04:49:15.651867Z'` is NOT valid MySQL datetime literal. Use STR_TO_DATE() function and extract correct datetime value. PS. This is not good practice to store datetime values as strings.

Comment: @Akina : I use `day(str_to_date(time)) = 21` and still does not work?

Comment: @Strawberry: I did not get that?

Comment: [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) functions needs correct pattern to be specified.

Comment: @Akina: Can you let me know which pattern I should use to get it worked?

Comment: I give you the link to the User Manual. Please read, study and apply. Do it once... otherwise you'll always ask about help...

Comment: @Strawberry: I want to select timestamps with the same day and put them into a new table.

Comment: @Strawberry: I want to decompose my table to daily tables and convert them to dataframe and analyze them using pandas in Python. The current way of table is not manageable for me. Hope this clarify my intention.

Comment: @Strawberry: I am not SQL coder and manipulating things for me in Python is easier. I want to have smaller tables so that I can convert them quickly to dataframe and analyse them. I am glad you are asking these questions because maybe I am wrong and there would be an easier way.

Comment: I'm just sceptical that your proposed solution is quicker than executing a simple SELECT, that's all.

Comment: @Strawberry: Now I get it. You are saying I can query suing SELECT and store the result as a dataframe without doing all of this?

Comment: Yep; that's the general idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should not be storing date/time values as strings.  So, I recommend that you fix your data model.

But, if you happen to have data in that format, you can use string functions:

```
where time like '%-20T%'
```

Or if you really want data from the same *date* and not day of the month, then:

```
where time like '2020-10-20%'
```

I emphasize that this is only appropriate because `time` is stored as a string, not a proper date/time.  If the column were stored using a correct type, then you would use date/time functions.

Comment: I will take that advice and let the time be in a time format.

Comment: I am new to sql that is why I am asking the following. Can you please help me to convert my table to the one that has time. Currently I have `time VARCHAR(60)` should I use `time TIMESTAMP` to capture all I have as `2020-10-19T04:49:15.651867Z`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS     
(SELECT * FROM old_table WHERE DAY(STR_TO_DATE(time, '%Y-%m-%dT%T.%fZ')) = 20)
```

e.g. Using your example,

```
SELECT DAY(STR_TO_DATE('2020-10-19T04:49:15.651867Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%T.%fZ')) ==> 19
```